# Is there a way to put the current page URL in an if statement?

Tags: php

I have a variable called `$user`, which gets the value after the `?u=` in the URL.

I am trying to set a condition which goes something like this - `if the value after the ?u= in the URL is equal to $user, then do this ...`

But I have no idea as to how I can get the current page URL. Is it even possible?

Comment: Checkout [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get information on the URL, and [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) for URL parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = $_GET['u'];
if ($user == $url){
   //Your Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_GET['u']){
   //Making sure that variable is set, otherwise while getting it return error
   $url = $_GET['u'];
   if ($user == $url){
       //Your Code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
echo $_GET["u"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<?php 
if($user == $_REQUEST['u']){
 echo 'condition true';
}
?>
```